# Right to left menu items Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have an Slide menu as picture one. And i need to align its items title to be right to left like slide two . I tried gravity=right but didn't work.

Here is my code :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:layout_gravity="end">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="end">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_24dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:title="آگهی خود را ثبت کنید"/>

</menu>
```

[image]

The desired menu will be :

[image]

Comment: These two pictures look the same to me?

Comment: with RTL languages you should use "start" and "end" instead of "left" and "right"

Comment: how does the layout XML for your drawer look like?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to influence the layout when using a menu resource. You may need to define the layout as you would normally do it and handle the clicks yourself. Check this Android Developers Training on building a drawer: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: @pooya  Thanks pooya , to which element should I add this property , I added to group and items and drawer layout (gravity=end) but not worked

Comment: @AliEsmaeili have you also tried "start"?

Comment: @pooya No, that didn't work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**To create right to left menu you just need to add** *android:layoutDirection="rtl"* **to the menu tag**

---

> android:layoutDirection="rtl"

---

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:layout_gravity="end">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="end">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_24dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:title="آگهی خود را ثبت کنید"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

you can see here the source:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LayoutDirection.html#LTR

**api 17 and above**

Comment: Perfectly works ! thanks.To complete your answer it should also be added  to <NavigationView> object.

Comment: This menu is not an options menu.

Comment: Do you know answer of this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61692792/how-can-i-have-one-item-of-menu-rtl-and-another-one-ltr

Answer (score 3):

if you are going to change your Menu direction which is inside a DrawerLayout just add

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

to your NavigationView element. output should be like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Comment: I have just a menu, not navigationview, how can I set for that?

Answer (score 1):

The layoutDirection attribute should be added to the parent activity layout XML:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

Answer (score 0):

in res>values>styles
add bellow item :
rtl

and then in toolbar or your navigation menu XML tag add:
android:textDirection="rtl"
android:layoutDirection="ltr"