# how to Right To Left my menu items in android

Tags: android, menu, gravity, android-layout-direction

I want to make an RTL menu.
I have read this page: [Right to left menu items Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517082/right-to-left-menu-items-android)
and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LayoutDirection.html#LTR
but they didn't help me.
I have added android:supportsRtl="true" to the manifest file.
and here is the xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_gravity="end">
    <item android:title="تنظیمات">
    <item android:title="درباره">
    ...
```

but it is still ltr.
I have also tried:

```
android:gravity="right"
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

but it doesn't work either.

TIA.

Comment: It's unclear from your question what exactly you're trying to achieve, and what the exact problem is.  "it doesn't work" is unhelpful.

Comment: My menu items are written left to right. And I want them to be right to left. This is what I want to do. But the related links didn't help me.